# have somebody doing

Tags: experiential-have

Please take a look at the sentence below:

> You know how we have those clients visiting at work next week?

I learned 'have somebody v-ing' sometimes means that 'to get someone to do something'.

For example> **I had Tom visiting your place to get your stuff back**. (Please check if the sentence okay as well.)

I think in this case the sentence means :

> You know how we are going to serve the clients who are visiting next week?

Is my idea right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the meaing of the sentence is as you put it in the last block quote.

> You know how we are going to serve the clients who are visiting next
>   week?

**I think it is a way of expressing a situation that is about to happen in a certain moment** (for that specific context).

*Person A* is stating to *Person B* that there will be some clients visiting at work next week. They might perform some work related actions but they are out of context right now.

## For example:

**Person A:**  "You know how we had those meteors crashing down in Russia last year?

**Person B:** "Yeah, I know. How about them?"

**Person A:** "Turns out they have high density of metal in them."

In my example, Person A is talking about an event that happened in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still wonder why the speaker say 'how' in the sentence. Here is more context   A: Get this.  You know how we have those clients visiting at work next week? B: Uh-huh.
A: Well, my boss and I were supposed to take them out to dinner on Wednesday night.  But this morning, she walks into my office and tells me she can’t make it after all.

Comment: Can I also say without 'how'? ... like.. 'You know we have those clients visiting at work next week?

Comment: Yes. In this context, it does not change the meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think your understanding is correct.

The nature of the obligation with **have** varies, but it remains obligation nonetheless. It can be the obligation to obey a command or follow an instruction, or the more tenuous obligation of something that has been arranged or planned for the near future.

> I had him wash the car, since it was he who had driven it on a muddy
>   road.

He who drove the car through the mud *must* wash the car. He has been told to do so.

> We have guests coming next week.

They will come. It has been arranged. This visit is in our future.

> He can't meet us for lunch. He says he has to go to the dentist.